# How to make jboss accept %2F encoded slash in URL path

Tags: java, web-services, resteasy, urlencode, jboss-eap-6

**URL:http://localhost:8080/admin/users/8VHlQMoMAeGAfwADT%2FtM2Q%3D%3D**

When i try to hit the above URL using advanced rest client, i am getting **400:Bad Request**.
I need special characters to be passed in URl path via URL encoding only. But %2F is not being accepted.How to enable jboss to accept encoded slash in url? kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have to know that JBoss by default is not allowing the escaped slashes in paths for security reasons.
However you can set the following system property to `true`

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH
```

Comment: AHH! Thank you Mr.Panagiotis...It works...Now URL accepts %2F...however %5C is not getting accepted...any idea..pls help?

Comment: Hi all, used this system property tag in Jboss's standalone.xml file...now it works fine...thanks 
-<system-properties>

<property value="true" name="org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder.ALLOW_ENCODED_SLASH"/>

<property value="true" name="org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.ALLOW_BACKSLASH"/>

<property value="UTF-8" name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING"/>

<property value="true" name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING"/>

</system-properties>

Comment: Documentation of system properties can be found here, in case anybody wonders: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/5/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/jbossweb#JBossWeb-SystemProperties